# Generating AD Kerberos tickets without user password

Tags: active-directory, kerberos, spnego

I am developing a Java EE server application that needs to generate a Kerberos ticket on behalf of a user.

The application I am developing will authenticate the user using alternate credentials (non Active Directory, say biometric), and then needs to somehow generate a Kerberos ticket showing the user is authenticated. I will then use the Kerberos ticket, to generate a SPNEGO token, and insert the token in the HTTP header so the user does not have to be re-authenticated on subsequent requests from the browser.

Is is possible to generate that Kerberos ticket on behalf of the user without the user's raw AD password ? (assume I have access to an AD Service Account login & password). If it is possible, how would I go about doing it? What kind of configuration, permissions are necessary?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that is possible. Microsoft has extended Kerberos for this. This is called Services for User (S4U). Your case is called `S4U2Self` (protocol transition). This will be avaible with Java 8. You can check the [ticket](http://www.mail-archive.com/security-dev@openjdk.java.net/msg05393.html) and add that code to your Java endorsed classpath. You can read more in the [MIT Kerberos wiki](http://k5wiki.kerberos.org/wiki/Projects/Services4User).

Comment: Glad I was able to help you. If you get this working, please share your experience. You might ant to upvote my answer too.

Comment: Please note that you will need to obtain the UPN from the client somehow.