# Postdatable Kerberos tickets in Java

Tags: java, kerberos, gssapi

I need a [postdatable Kerberos ticket](http://www.cmf.nrl.navy.mil/krb/kerberos-faq.html#postdate) in my Java application. But I did not find any method in the `GSSContext` interface. Does Java not support this Kerberos feature?

The purpose is as follows:
In our application, users can set up a batch that will run some time in the future. And the application server will have to use a delegated ticket that is valid at execution time of teh batch, when the original ticket may have expired.

EDIT: To clarify my first statement: I found that `GSSContext`, `GSSContextImpl` as well as the `GSSContextImpl` do not give access to the `setAuthTime()` method which is only available in `Krb5Context`. Without having dug into all details, it seems the postdated authentication would only be possible with some direct access to undocumented classes.

As there seem to be additional problems in getting a client browser to send a ticket with the correct flags set - as @Michael-O pointed out -, I think I will have to find another solution, maybe just asking the user for username and password, saving them encrypted with the batch, and then just requesting a new ticket at batch start time.

The concept of postdated tickets sounds appropriate for my problem, but there seems to be a lack of practical use, resulting in it not being well supported by existing environments.

Comment: Frank, did you actually read chapter 2.4 of the [RFC4120](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4120.txt)?. The TGT from the client must have the initial flag `MAY-POSTDATE`. Please check that first. Yes, Java GSS supports that but I haven't tried that myself. See [this](http://i.imgur.com/VPXrA.png) search.

Comment: Good point! As the client is a browser, maybe I cannot influence its ticket setting.

Comment: I have checked `kinit` unter Ubuntu and I am able to set the startdate for the ticket (TGT) => postdatable. I also checked my Windows credential cache with `kerbtray` and the TGT is not `MAY-POSTDATE`. Since SSPI uses this given TGT and you cannot have a postdated forwarded TGT, as far as I understand. You should raise this very specific question at the MIT Kerbros mailing list. I would really like to hear devs' opinion.

Comment: @FrankPl: What is the specific use case of a postdatable ticket in a web application / browser? Sounds interesting.

Comment: @Koraktor: As described above, our application allows the users to create some batch jobs that are scheduled to be executed at a certain date/time in future. Those jobs require access to another application via http(s). Currently, the execution does not require a user specific authentication. But it is a requirement for the next version of the application to use the authentication of the user who runs the client within the browser. And here we come to the problem that Kerberos tickets by default expire after 10 hours, maybe before the scheduled job is executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides my comment:

> Frank, did you actually read chapter 2.4 of the [RFC4120](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4120.txt)?. The TGT from the client must have the initial flag `MAY-POSTDATE`. Please check that first. Yes, Java GSS supports that but I haven't tried that myself. See [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QaycX.png) search.

Frank, there *is* a solution to your problem. Just came to me yesterday. I have answered this already. It may be a bit of work to backport this code but it is worth it.

See [Generating AD Kerberos tickets without user password](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13806117/696632).

Comment: Thank you for this. Anyway, I think we will stick to the solution to ask the user for user name and password (as this is the case in the current version of the application anyway, so no change from a users perspective), and then just generate a new ticket on the server at the point in time when we need one.

Comment: That works but isn't really elegant. Your approach will fail in the twilight of password expiry/change and re-providing the new one.

Comment: I completely agree. But I have to balance effort and outcome.

Comment: After some thoughts maybe the problem with expired passwords is also one that will happen with the postdated tickets that I had in mind originally - as the encryption/decryption of a ticket is done using a key that is derived from the users password. But actually, I do not know. The behavior of re-validating a ticket after password changes is not specified in the RFC.

Comment: I do not think that this will happen because the KDC knows when a password expires and should support that twilight interval. You can do a very simple test: Login into Windows, obtain TGT. Change password on another machine. Get back to machine one an try to get a service ticket with the old TGT. This should work.